# Angularjs async callback return undefined under $scope.$apply();

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

This is my factory code. The callback is async so i put it under $rootScope.safeApply(). 
Then I call console.log(authService.authUser) in my controller but it still return undefined when user logged in. But it is find if user not login and will show 'not login' in console. Any idea?

```
myapp.factory('authService', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    var auth = {};
    $rootScope.safeApply = function(fn) {
      var phase = this.$root.$$phase;
      if (phase == '$apply' || phase == '$digest') {
        if(fn && (typeof(fn) === 'function')) {
            fn();
        }
      } else {
        this.$apply(fn);
      }
    };    
    auth.firebaseAuthClient = new FirebaseAuthClient(FIREBASEREF, function(error, user) {
        $rootScope.safeApply(function() {
            if (user) {
                auth.authUser = user;
                //auth.isLoggedIn = true;
            } else if (error) {
                auth.authError = error;
            } else {
                auth.not = 'not login';
                //auth.isLoggedIn = false;
            }
        });
    });

    auth.login = function() {
        this.firebaseAuthClient.login('facebook');
    };

    auth.logout = function() {
        this.firebaseAuthClient.logout();   
    };

    return auth;
}]);
```

**UPDATED**

```
auth.callback = function(error, user) {
    if (user) {
        deferred.resolve(user);
    } else if (error) {
        deferred.reject(error);
    } else {
        //deferred.reject('not login');  // there is no callback value here
    }
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

in controller

```
callback().then(function(response) {
  $scope.isLoggedIn = true;
}, function(response) {
  $scope.isLoggedIn = false //How can i set false here?
});
```

**UPDATE 2**

Now every thing work fine, I'm able to monitoring user login state. But still having a problem. Check the code below

```
authService.callback().then(function(success){
  $rootScope.isLoggedIn = true; //If promise return success set isLoggedIn true
}, function(fail){
   **//If user not login set isLoggedIn false;
   //I have problem here because i'm not able to deferred.reject below**
  $rootScope.isLoggedIn = false;
})

auth.callback = function(error, user) {
    $timeout(function() {
        if (user) {
            deferred.resolve(user);
        } else if (error) {
            deferred.reject(error);
        } else {
            //If this line is added,
            //.then() will not return anything not even undefined with no error,
            //No mater user logged-in or not login.
            //If I comment it out, everything will work fine but how can I 
            //set isLoggedIn = false?
            deferred.reject(); 
        }

    }, 0);
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: Use promises instead of that hacky safeApply stuff. http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q

Comment: @OlivérKovács   hi,  i updated my question using $q ..can you check it again?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the outside service's deferred resolve in a $timeout block to let angular know when its resolved. This way when your controller runs then callback, it'll be in a $digest cycle.

See this fiddle as a working proof of concept: http://jsfiddle.net/Zmetser/rkJKt/

```js
// in controller
authService.login().then(success, error);

// service
myapp.factory('authService', ['$q', '$timeout', function( $q, $timeout ) {
    var auth = {},
      deferred;

    firebaseAuthClient = new FirebaseAuthClient(FIREBASEREF, afterAuth);

    function afterAuth( error, user ) {
        // Let angular know the deferred has been resolved.
        $timeout(function () {
          if (user) {
              deferred.resolve(user);
          } else if (error) {
              deferred.reject(error);
          } else {
              deferred.reject();  // there is no callback value here
          }
        }, 0);
    }

    auth.login = function() {
        deferred = $q.defer();
        firebaseAuthClient.login('facebook');

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    auth.logout = function() {
        deferred = $q.defer();
        firebaseAuthClient.logout(); 

        return deferred.promise;  
    };

    return auth;
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if i want `afterAuth()` standalone? because I want to use it to check user login state without trigger `.login('facebook')`

Comment: basically, i want to check if user logged-in in every route

Comment: AfterAuth is a callback. How do you want is standalone? Once the user logged in save the state to the service, or get it from the server, when you want. auth.loggedIn()

Comment: Ok, let me try again... come back later.

Comment: Ok, after some tries, return promise in `.login()` and `.logout()` is not what I want. What I meant standalone is actually pull the callback out from `FirebaseAuthClient`. This is because I can use `authService.afterAuth().then()` to monitoring user login state without trigger `.login()`. Now everything work find but there is still a problem. Please check my update2